# How to check XML with monoid in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, monoids

Suppose I need to validate an input XML, e.g.

```
<a>
  <a1>a1a1a1</a1>
  <a2>a2a2a2</a2>
  <a3/>
</a>
```

I need to make sure that its root element has label `"a"` and  children with labels `"a1"`, `"a2"`, `"a3"` and texts `"a1a1a1"`, `"a2a2a2"` and `""` respectively.

I can define the basic validation functions as follows:

```
type Status = ... // either Ok or list of error messages
type Validate[A] = A => Status
type ValidateNode = Validate[scala.xml.Node]

val label(l: String): ValidateNode = ... // trivial
val text(t: String): ValidateNode =  ... // trivial
val child(vn: ValidateNode) = ... // find such a child "c" that "vn(c)" is Ok
```

Since `Status` is a monoid (isomorphic to list) then `Validate[A]` is a monoid too and we can compose the validation functions with `|+|`

```
val a1: ValidateNode = label("a1") |+| text("a1a1a1")
val a2: ValidateNode = label("a2") |+| text("a2a2a2") 
val a3: ValidateNode = label("a3")
val a:  ValidateNode = label("a") |+| child(a1) |+| child(a2) |+| child(a3)
```

Does it make sense ? How would you fix/improve it ?

Comment: This looks reasonable, but if you're using Scalaz (?) is there a reason you wouldn't just go with `ValidationNel`?

Comment: I thought about `ValidationNel[String, Unit]` but it _felt_ like  an overkill. What I _really_ need is just a list, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, `ValidationNel[String, Unit]` is isomorphic to `List[String]`, but the former is much clearer about your intent (and some of the combinators on `Validation` could be useful, depending on what you're doing).

Comment: Well ... maybe I should re-consider `ValidationNel`. Thank you for the input.