# Validating a sequence of XML elements with Writer monad

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz, writer-monad

This is a follow-up to my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803455/how-to-check-xml-with-monoid-in-scala).

Suppose I need to validate an XML:

```
<a><a1/><a2/><a3/></a>
```

I need to make sure that the root `a` has children `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` (in this order).

I'd like to use a `List` (instead of `scalaz.Validation`) and `Writer` monad to collect validation errors. So I define a function to validate a sequence of XML elements like this:

```
type Validate = List[Elem] => Writer[List[String], List[Elem]]
```

Now I can add a function to validate the label of an XML element:

```
val label: String => Validate = ...
```

If I redefine `Validate` as `Kleisli` I'll be able to compose the `Validate` functions with `andThen` :

```
val children: Validate = label("a1") andThen label("a2") andThen label("a3")
```

Doest it make sense ? How would you correct/simplify it ?