# Validating XML with Writer and Kleisli in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli, writer-monad

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973056/validating-a-sequence-of-xml-elements-with-writer-monad)

Suppose I need to validate an XML like this:

```
<a><a1>xxx<a1/><a2>yyy</a2><a3>zzz</a3></a>
```

I need to make sure that the root element has label `a` and also has children `<a1>xxx</a1>`, `<a2>yyy</a2>`, `<a3>zzz</a3>` in this order.

I'd like to use `List[String]` to collect errors and define a function to validate a single XML element like this:

```
type ValidateSingleElement = Elem => List[String]
```

Now I can write functions to validate the label, text, and attributes of a given XML element:

```
val label : String => ValidateSingleElement = ...
val text  : String => ValidateSingleElement = ...
val attr  : (String, String) => ValidateSingleElement = ...
```

I can compose these functions with `|+|` since `ValidateSingleElement` is a monoid.

```
val a1 = label("a1") |+| text("xxx") // validate both label and text
```

Now I need a function to validate the children of a given element. In order to write such a function I need another function to validate a *sequence* of elements

```
val children: ValidateElements => ValidateSingleElement = ...
```

The `ValidateElements` is defined as follows:

```
type ValidateElements = List[Elem] => Writer[List[String], List[Elem]]
```

I am using the `List[String]` and `Writer` monad to collect errors while traversing the sequence of elements.

Now I can write a function to validate the children of a given element:

```
val children: ValidateElements => ValidateSingleElement = 
  validateElements => {e =>
    val kids = e.child collect {case e:Elem => e}
    val writer = validateElements(kids.toList)
    writer.written
  }
```

... and validate the first element of the sequence:

```
 val child: ValidateSingleElement => ValidateElements = validate => {
   _ match {
     case e:es => Writer(validate(e), es)
     case _    => Writer(List("Unexpected end of input"), Nil)
   }
 }
```

Finally I can re-define `ValidateElements` as `Kleisli`

```
type ErrorsWriter[A]  = Writer[List[String], A]
type ValidateElements = Kliesli[ErrorsWriter, List[Elem], List[Elem]]
```

... and re-write the `child` to return the `Kleisli` instead of the function.

Given both the `child` and `children` I can write `a` -- a validating function for the XML from above:

```
val a1 = label("a1") |+| text("xxx")
val a2 = label("a2") |+| text("yyy")
val a3 = label("a3") |+| text("zzz")
val a  = label("a")  |+| children(child(a1) >=> child(a2) >=> child(a3))
```

Does it make sense ? How would you correct/extend this design ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `Writer[List[String], A]` instead of `ValidationNel[String, A]` ?

Comment: I'd like to compose `child` functions with `>=>`. How can I compose functions of type `List[Elem] => ValidationNel[String, List[Elem]]` ?

Comment: You'd need to import `Validation.FlatMap._` and provide you own `Bind` instance, for example like in https://gist.github.com/channingwalton/3230464

Comment: @Kolmar Thanks, interesting. What are advantages of this solution in comparison with mine ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I believe `|+|` and `>=>` stay the same. `ValidationNel[YourErrorType, ResultType]` seems to be more semantically correct, than `Writer[List[YourErrorType], ResultType]` – you get *either* a non-empty list of errors, *or* the result. It's a little bit more convenient to work with validations than with writers (`foo.failureNel`, etc.). But you have to work through this `Bind[Validation ...]` instance which many people find a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why would many people consider `Bind[Validation ...]` bad practice ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in most cases you don't want to only validate an XML document, you want to create some meaningful business object from it, and your code doesn't seem to allow for that. I think Play's type-class based Json library is a good model for how to do this. It allows you to define `Reads` objects, where a `Reads[A]` is essentially a `JsValue => Either[Errors, A]`. These can be flexibly combined with a bunch of combinators shipped with the library.

Comment: It can, you just need to provide a suitable Applicative instance. Anyway, it's irrelevant because a Reads[A] is not a function type and its reads method doesn't return Either but JsResult (and Errors isn't even a type). Now you can complain about those details, or you can think about why it says "essentially".

Comment: I am bit confused, sorry. How would you define a function to validate a sequence of XML elements and collect the validation errors ? Please note that I don't use `play` and would not like to add it as a dependency.